# Why is there a white page on my image slider?

Tags: html, css

So I know very little about coding and was trying to make a html and css only slider. I was able to create a really basic slideshow with three images. However, the code places a white image after the third for some weird reason. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong? Why is there a white page after the last image? Also if possible, how can I make it so that after the last image it doesn't look choppy when it cuts back to the first?

```css
@keyframes slider {

0% {
  left: 0;
}

20% {
  left: 0;
}

25% {
  left: -100%;
}

45% {
  left: -100%;
}

50% {
  left: -200%;
}

70% {
  left: -200%;
}

75% {
  left: -300%;
}

95% {
  left: -300%;
}

100% {
  left: -400%;
}

}

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 15s  infinite slider;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
  <img src="http://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/fire-beach-widescreen-high-definition-wallpaper-pictures-download-full-free-download-wallpaper-high-resolution-colorful-2048x1367-736x459.jpg">
  <img src="http://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/awesome-malaysiwide-hdesktop-backgrounphotos-windows-desktop-images-mac-wallpapers-colorful-2048x1367-736x459.jpg">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/bf/2e/c5/bf2ec5d03e6ddb65bbff4c98ae367a36.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is not the white image, that is the background color of the  page/div, if you change the color of it, white color will be changed accordingly. hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have 3 images if you put `left: -300%;` the last image is out of the container.

Here is the fix:

```css
@keyframes slider {

0% {
  left: 0;
}

20% {
  left: 0;
}

25% {
  left: -100%;
}

45% {
  left: -100%;
}

50% {
  left: -200%;
}

70% {
  left: -200%;
}

75% {
  left: 0;
}

95% {
  left: 0;
}

100% {
  left: 0;
}

}

#slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider figure img {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}

#slider figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 15s  infinite slider;
}
```

```html
<div id="slider">
  <figure>
  <img src="http://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/fire-beach-widescreen-high-definition-wallpaper-pictures-download-full-free-download-wallpaper-high-resolution-colorful-2048x1367-736x459.jpg">
  <img src="http://thewallpaper.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/awesome-malaysiwide-hdesktop-backgrounphotos-windows-desktop-images-mac-wallpapers-colorful-2048x1367-736x459.jpg">
  <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/bf/2e/c5/bf2ec5d03e6ddb65bbff4c98ae367a36.jpg">
  </figure>
</div>
```

> Note that when you are on the last image - the next slide (to the first one) will not be from the right to the left. To get that visual effect you will have to use javascript.

Comment: I know a bit of javascript/jquery, do you know where I could start to do this?

Comment: If you want this for training you should think about positioning the element before/after the last element in your slider. If you just need the solution - search for a slider library :) there are plenty of them.